# Tkinter program compiled with pyinstaller crash on launch

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm asking help today because I'm new to Tkinter and Pyinstaller (and python in general) and I'm having troubles with it.

I have a simple app working with sqlite, tkinter and pyinstaller to compile all of this in an executable program, the entrance point of my program is a file named `main.py`

This file calls all the dependancies (like the sqlite module for python, tkinter and my other files like classes etc...)

I made a very simple interface, with a *Hello World* in a tkinter label and a button to go to page 2 which displays *page2* (also in a label), just to see if I'm capable of making it all run and compile all of these pieces together.

I can run it throught my shell executing it like : `python main.py` and everything is working fine.

But when I run pyinstaller on my linux machine, and start executing the program, nothing appears, my database.db (sqlite database file) is created but I don't have any interface like when I run it with my shell. The thing is getting even worse on windows where, once I've my `.exe` it just opens a shell and crash after few seconds, not even creating the database.

What I did is I created a 'log file', in which I write the steps of the program.

As you can see on the following picture, the 2 first prints are wrote in my log file (on linux), so I think it crashes when I try to create the window.

[image]

If any of you have an idea on what I do wrong, I would really appreciate help :)

Comment: You'd have to see what it doesn't like in `Window`.

Comment: For simple debugging purposes (not recommended generally) can you put the whole thing in a `try`. Once the error is raised, you can save the traceback (`traceback.format_exc()`) to a file and hence find your problem.

Answer (score 1):

### General

From the PyInstaller manual:

> Before you attempt to bundle to one file, make sure your app works correctly when bundled to one folder. It is is much easier to diagnose problems in one-folder mode.

As the comments suggested, use a catch-all `try`/`except` block to log all exceptions to a file. That is probably the best way to see what is really happening. Make sure that the logfile is created in an existing location where you have the necessary permissions.

I would suggest to take advantage of the built-in `logging` module instead of creating your own. It can e.g. automatically add from which file a log line was created.

IMHO, it is probable that the failures on Linux and ms-windows have completely different causes. You should probably treat them as different issues.

### Linux

When you use single file mode, that file is unpacked into a temporary folder, probably somewhere in `/tmp`. Some Linux distributions mount the `/tmp` filesystem with the `noexec` flag. This is incompatible with PyInstaller.

### ms-windows

On windows, there are basically two different Pythons; `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`. Basically it is one of the quirks of windows that this is necessary. The latter is for GUI programs like `tkinter` programs. A tkinter script should not show a `cmd` window.  So I'm guessing that PyInstaller calls your command with `python.exe` instead of `pythonw.exe`. From the manual:

> By default the bootloader creates a command-line console (a terminal window in GNU/Linux and Mac OS, a command window in Windows). It gives this window to the Python interpreter for its standard input and output. Your script’s use of print and input() are directed here. Error messages from Python and default logging output also appear in the console window.
>
> An option for Windows and Mac OS is to tell PyInstaller to not provide a console window. The bootloader starts Python with no target for standard output or input. Do this when your script has a graphical interface for user input and can properly report its own diagnostics.
>
> As noted in the CPython tutorial Appendix, for Windows a file extention of .pyw suppresses the console window that normally appears. Likewise, a console window will not be provided when using a myscript.pyw script with PyInstaller.

Also, on windows it can matter which Python distribution you're using. I used to be a fan of Anaconda, but lately I've come to prefer the `python.org` version because it gives me less headaches. On anaconda Python I had the problem that tkinter programs would not launch without showing a `cmd` window, whatever I tried. Only switching to `python.org` Python solved that problem.